# Outlook Exception that doesn't make sense

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop

Using Outlook 2010, I get this error when debugging

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component

```
    public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK()
    {
        try
        {
            String address = "john.doe@contoso.com";

            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); // CRASHING HERE
            oMailItem.To = address;

            oMailItem.Subject = "Status Update on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");

            oMailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain;                

            oMailItem.Body = createEmailBody();
            // body, bcc etc...
            oMailItem.Display(true);
        }//end of try block
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }//end of catch
    }
```

This code worked PERFECTLY on Outlook 2013. However it keeps crashing when using Outlook 2010.

I downgraded the Interop.Outlook from 15 to 14

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/39773b51-6a08-4753-ab45-4fe748c2ca2d/error-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoftofficeinteropoutlookapplicationclass-to?forum=outlookdev), it may help.

Comment: @kelix the code on the referenced site is VB.Net. The answers refer to a corrupt Office install but I know my Office is not corrupt since it was a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace this:

```
Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

with this:

```
Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Also, if this code is in an add-in, you don't need to create a new instance of Outlook.Application - use the object passed to the OnConnection event.